# numpy mean azimuth with functools.reduce

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

From the left to the right column calculating the mean azimuth, and using that mean value to calculate the subsequent columns mean value

### data (azimuth radians)

```py
DATA = [[-2.3843975194179015, -2.7958149137126727, -2.6810230389823926], [0.0, -0.33324870390860456, 1.9163397142483196], [-2.775696989543418, -2.6275328191212055, -3.0806691230131427], [-2.6165411867482886, -2.8296789582836546, -2.759783341076573], [-2.616424963417955, -2.350064069320187, -2.64689261457977], [1.104212457007189, -2.515201986722916, -2.2069283847977026], [-2.8856028734085193, -3.035199951833442, -2.9077720348345553], [-2.293023583373838, -2.740650128255022, -3.025816070768775], [-2.661380976757957, -2.696160756125776, -2.797445318924053], [-2.672558649603817, 1.1374747396080642, 0.49873606783869645], [-2.891086359150823, -2.534688380524549, -2.8613440140805824], [-2.1102972290491526, -2.7231458620637, 2.5363950091287175], [-2.7499793569484, -2.781083646511631, -2.620954273599801], [-2.5524999373379402, 3.0935259791770524, -3.0773177380372885], [1.823611047211595, -1.4712997025244356, 1.342893346423129], [-2.17176255369712, -1.8898609834910174, -2.268499047776501], [0.0, 0.3051469200248977, 0.0], [0.0, 2.686707754196432, 0.3181841090845195], [-2.013127032273615, -2.585833601042828, -2.2394210436859248], [-1.8632234178313352, 1.6384133633813605, 0.0], [0.0, -2.5772232960065735, -2.3263137464465733], [-2.7073814222954895, -2.6500018958867892, -2.6400076935381716], [2.6869128840921395, 0.0, 1.9253389809746972], [-2.2915544202470555, -2.623936997218667, -3.0737947196860658], [-3.070289814572786, 1.0808289734593535, -2.8021148149172457], [-2.4204628750723356, -1.8818522770306059, 1.6542127874142347], [-1.9368378050906847, 0.7201295933844157, -0.17929292417475493], [-2.595272316663131, -2.9438016727613667, -2.6436993422121198], [0.0, 0.2440343245870421, 2.444363530333403], [-2.1107094783452096, -2.218138330346221, -0.23776292567384266], [-2.608579570855172, -2.625201629076177, -2.5100755182494647], [-2.536785971275389, -2.4152229583675955, -2.7570482180653295], [-2.462458634843743, -2.588131847455644, 0.25493101832357806], [3.050624146100454, -2.196117753263519, -2.66463670917082], [-2.80535723354294, -2.3745291584752883, -2.81889385577244], [0.0, 2.886624426749002, 0.018485826949280033], [-3.0495850181137567, -0.2673600226034394, -1.7137044666766026], [0.0, -1.294898562056998, -1.825024233632855], [-2.8304708163091155, -2.8662907738811017, -2.8824638579419415], [-2.8066970357210623, -2.6752770379771706, -2.9351942988074335], [0.0, 0.9298682819793824, -0.08811157028633422], [0.0, -2.568012404513931, 0.6884719675459386], [-3.0003195279475836, -3.0100041905183095, 2.997899232919756], [None, 0.0, 0.22184922358564446], [None, 2.0513956490022247, 0.0], [None, 3.139803691103381, -0.23697917750286965], [None, -2.314698060002942, -2.2962275991831933], [None, 0.0, 0.2470592881115847], [None, -2.2270407983925375, -2.379935787161442], [None, -2.7200551654310563, -3.013393418145732], [None, -2.9700772916183, -2.626022914672403], [None, None, -2.646662549139035], [None, None, -2.713921422380295], [None, None, 0.0], [None, None, -2.3713496027483574], [None, None, -2.826763915677864], [None, None, 2.4941269118667955], [None, None, -0.21200517436725835], [None, None, -0.47227943847233556], [None, None, 3.078678341388149], [None, None, 2.307358803457483]]
```

### main.py

```py
import functools
import numpy as np

def _mean_reduction(col1: np.ndarray, col2: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    # where col1 is nan use the col2 value
    col1[np.isnan(col1)] = col2[np.isnan(col1)]

    mean_rads = (
        np.arctan2(np.sin(col1)+np.sin(col2), np.cos(col1)+np.cos(col2)))

    return mean_rads


def start(azi:np.ndarray) -> None:
    """calc mean azimuth"""
    # the 0 values are 99% likely an error in the data so nan them to ignore
    azi[azi == 0] = np.nan

    mean_rads = functools.reduce(
        _mean_reduction,
        # start ittr with the second column
        np.swapaxes(azi[:, 1:, np.newaxis], 0, 1),
        # init with first column
        azi[:, 0, np.newaxis]
    )

    print(np.rint(np.rad2deg(np.column_stack([azi, mean_rads])) % 360))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start(np.array(DATA, dtype=float))
```

### result in degs

```
[[223. 200. 206. 209.]
 [341. 341. 110.  45.]
 [201. 209. 183. 194.]
 [210. 198. 202. 203.]
 [210. 225. 208. 213.]
 [ 63. 216. 234. 187.]
 [195. 186. 193. 192.]
 [229. 203. 187. 201.]
 [208. 206. 200. 203.]
 [207.  65.  29.  82.]
 [194. 215. 196. 200.]
 [239. 204. 145. 183.]
 [202. 201. 210. 206.]
 [214. 177. 184. 190.]
 [104. 276.  77. 134.]
 [236. 252. 230. 237.]
 [ 17.  17.  nan  nan]
 [154. 154.  18.  86.]
 [245. 212. 232. 230.]
 [253.  94.  nan  nan]
 [212. 212. 227. 220.]
 [205. 208. 209. 208.]
 [154.  nan 110. 110.]
 [229. 210. 184. 202.]
 [184.  62. 199. 161.]
 [221. 252.  95. 166.]
 [249.  41. 350. 337.]
 [211. 191. 209. 205.]
 [ 14.  14. 140.  77.]
 [239. 233. 346. 291.]
 [211. 210. 216. 213.]
 [215. 222. 202. 210.]
 [219. 212.  15. 295.]
 [175. 234. 207. 206.]
 [199. 224. 198. 205.]
 [165. 165.   1.  83.]
 [185. 345. 262. 263.]
 [286. 286. 255. 271.]
 [198. 196. 195. 196.]
 [199. 207. 192. 197.]
 [ 53.  53. 355.  24.]
 [213. 213.  39. 126.]
 [188. 188. 172. 180.]
 [ nan  nan  13.  13.]
 [118. 118.  nan  nan]
 [180. 180. 346. 263.]
 [227. 227. 228. 228.]
 [ nan  nan  14.  14.]
 [232. 232. 224. 228.]
 [204. 204. 187. 196.]
 [190. 190. 210. 200.]
 [ nan  nan 208. 208.]
 [ nan  nan 205. 205.]
 [ nan  nan  nan  nan]
 [ nan  nan 224. 224.]
 [ nan  nan 198. 198.]
 [ nan  nan 143. 143.]
 [ nan  nan 348. 348.]
 [ nan  nan 333. 333.]
 [ nan  nan 176. 176.]
 [ nan  nan 132. 132.]]
```

Comment: Is `azi` actually of size three in the smaller dimension, or will this increase?

Comment: It grows. The starting columns are a time series of information.  As the system runs more azimuths get added to the cache.  It should run at around a 2 min interval, with anything outside of 40 min being removed.  So a rough max of 20 per column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This conditional reassignment:

```
col1[np.isnan(col1)] = col2[np.isnan(col1)]
```

can be replaced with the purpose-built

```
np.nan_to_num(x=col1, nan=col2, copy=False)
```

If your `azi` grows bigger than 3 in the small axis, you'll want to get rid of `functools` and instead use `ufunc.reduce`.

Your use of `reduce` is needlessly complicated: you can let it use the default initialiser, and avoid slicing it yourself.

You can replace `swapaxes` with a single `.T`.

### Suggested

```py
def _mean_reduction(col1: np.ndarray, col2: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    # where col1 is nan, use the col2 value
    np.nan_to_num(x=col1, nan=col2, copy=False)

    return np.arctan2(
        np.sin(col1) + np.sin(col2),
        np.cos(col1) + np.cos(col2),
    )


def start() -> None:
    """calc mean azimuth"""
    azi = np.array(DATA, dtype=float)
    # the 0 values are 99% likely an error in the data so nan them to ignore
    azi[azi == 0] = np.nan

    mean_rads = functools.reduce(_mean_reduction, azi.T)

    assert np.allclose(mean_rads, MEAN_RADS_EXPECTED, equal_nan=True)
    assert np.allclose(azi, AZI_EXPECTED, equal_nan=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start()
```